# Haskell - Will lazy evaluation cause this foldr to stop evaulating all functions

Tags: haskell

func1, func2.. are all defined  :: [String]-> Bool

will the following fold stop evaluating the functions as soon as the first true is hit

```
foldr (\x acc -> acc ||  x ) False ( fmap ($ "111") [func1,func2, func3, func4])
```

---

Thinking about it I realized the fmap will evaluate all 4 functions then pass a [Bool] to the fold.. which should stop fold as soon as it hits a True.

I guess the question I need to ask is if there is a way to merge the fmap into the fold so it stops evaluating as soon as one of the functions returns true.

Comment: You say "Thinking about it I realized the fmap will evaluate all 4 functions then pass a [Bool] to the fold.. which should stop fold as soon as it hits a True". This is untrue. Just because it passes a `[Bool]` to the fold does *not* mean that the functions are evaluated. They are evaluated when they are needed: you can see when this happens for yourself if you step through the evaluation on paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function like your

```
foldr (\x acc -> acc || x) False
```

has already been written for you. It is in the standard library under the name [`or`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:or). Note that it flips the order of arguments to `(||)`, which is necessary for the short-circuiting you want. So, you can simplify your problem to

```
or . map ($ "111") $ fs
```

And happily, the idea of mapping a function over a list and `or`-ing together its results is *also* very common: witness [`any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any). So we can rewrite your whole expression to

```
any ($ "111") fs
```

so that we don't have to worry at all about the details: the people who wrote `any` were careful to not evaluate more of the list than necessary, so it's a solved problem from your point of view.

Comment: No, that isn't `or`, because its arguments to `||` are the wrong way around.

Answer (score 3):

Your `foldr` function uses `||` the wrong way around. You probably mean to write:

```hs
foldr (\x acc -> x || acc) False
```

Once you make that change, no, not all functions will be evaluated. You can see for yourself with `Debug.Trace`

```hs
main = print $ foldr (\x acc -> x || acc) False (fmap ($ True) [id, not, traceShowId, not])
```

This will print only one `True`, showing that the third function in the list isn't forced.